# insert commas in text string after certain words in r

Tags: r, regex, nlp, stringr

here is the example data:

```r
example_sentences <- data.frame(doc_id = c(1,2,3),
                                sentence_id = c(1,2,3),
                                sentence = c("problem not fixed","i like your service and would tell others","peope are nice however the product is rubbish"))
matching_df <- data.frame(x = c("not","and","however"))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I want to add/insert a comma just before a certain `word` in a character string. for example if my string is:

`problem not fixed.`

I want to convert this to

`problem, not fixed.`

The other `matching_df` contains the words to match (these are `Coordinate conjunctions`) so if the `x` is found in `matching_df` then insert `comma + space` before the `detected word`.

I have looked at `stringr` package but not sure how to achieve this.

Best,

Comment: @MrFlick I edited with the reprex example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no idea what the data frame you're talking about looks like, but I made a simple data frame containing some phrases here:

```
df <- data.frame(strings = c("problems not fixed.","Help how are you"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I then made a vector of words to put a comma after:

```
words <- c("problems","no","whereas","however","but")
```

Then I put the data frame of phrases through a simple for loop, using **gsub** to substitute the word for a word + comma:

```
for (i in 1:length(df$strings)) {
    string <- df$strings[i]
    findWords <- intersect(unlist(strsplit(string," ")),words)
    if (!is.null(findWords)) {
        for (j in findWords) {
            df$strings[i] <- gsub(j,paste0(j,","),string)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 df
               strings
1 problems, not fixed.
2     Help how are you
```

Comment: I edited the question but your solution looks good. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The `gsubfn` function in the gsubfn package takes a regular expression as the first argument and a list (or certain other objects) as the second argument where the names of the list are strings to be matched and the values in the list are the replacement strings.

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("\\w+", as.list(setNames(paste0(matching_df$x, ","), matching_df$x)), 
  format(example_sentences$sentence))
```

giving:

```
[1] "problem not, fixed                            "
[2] "i like your service and, would tell others    "
[3] "peope are nice however, the product is rubbish"
```

Comment: this is sick!! will give it a go today