# Placing Commas Between Names

Tags: r, regex, text

I am trying to find out if certain patterns appear within a data frame.

Suppose I have the following "dictionary of patterns" (notice "james" vs "jamesj"):

```
patterns <- c("john", "jack", "james", "jamesj", "jason")
```

The actual data frame ("date_frame") I have looks like this:

```
  id                                              names
1  1                                     johnjack jameS
2  2                             john/james, jasonjames
3  3                                    peter_jackjason
4  4                                   jamesjasonj jack
5  5 jamesjjason, johnjasonjohn , jason-jack sam _ peter
```

The final result I am trying to produce should look like this:

```
  id                                                         names
1  1                                             john, jack, james
2  2                                     john, james, jason, james
3  3                                            peter, jack, jason
4  4                                          jamesj, asonj,  jack
5  5 jamesj, jason, john, jason, john , jason, jack,  sam ,  peter
```

I tried looking at this post here ([R: insert comma after each element from the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103591/r-insert-comma-after-each-element-from-the-output)) and tried the answer provided there:

```
> data_frame$parsed_names = dput(data_frame$names)



  id                                                         names                                                  parsed_names
1  1                                             john, jack, james                                             john, jack, james
2  2                                     john, james, jason, james                                     john, james, jason, james
3  3                                            peter, jack, jason                                            peter, jack, jason
4  4                                          jamesj, asonj,  jack                                          jamesj, asonj,  jack
5  5 jamesj, jason, john, jason, john , jason, jack,  sam ,  peter jamesj, jason, john, jason, john , jason, jack,  sam ,  peter
```

But this is not corresponding to what I wanted.

I then tried this post over here ([insert commas in text string after certain words in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078683/insert-commas-in-text-string-after-certain-words-in-r)) and tried the answer provided there:

```
library(gsubfn)

data_frame$parsed_names = gsubfn("\\w+", as.list(setNames(paste0(patterns, ","), patterns)), 
  format(data_frame$names))

 data_frame
  id                                                         names                                                         parsed_names
1  1                                             john, jack, james     john,, jack,, james,                                            
2  2                                     john, james, jason, james    john,, james,, jason,, james,                                    
3  3                                            peter, jack, jason      peter, jack,, jason,                                           
4  4                                          jamesj, asonj,  jack      jamesj,, asonj,  jack,                                         
5  5 jamesj, jason, john, jason, john , jason, jack,  sam ,  peter jamesj,, jason,, john,, jason,, john, , jason,, jack,,  sam ,  peter
```

- Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: There are some elements such as 'sam' not in the patterns.  Do you want to keep it as it is?

Comment: yes - that is correct!

Comment: It is extremely unclear as to what are the rules to go from the starting column to the output you want. For the question to be helpful to anybody else in the future, it would be useful to clarify the transitions you want : Ex: replace special chars with `, ` , add `, ` between words present in the pattern etc.

Comment: Why not split `jamesjasonj` into `james, jason, j` as `james` and `jason` are in `patterns`?

Comment: In your desired output, did you really intend for there to be the extra space in `john ,` and `sam ,` in the last line or was that a typo?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a somewhat ad-hoc answer but it meets your requirements (no change in the `patterns` vector):

```r
library(tidyverse)
patterns <- c("john", "jack", "james", "jamesj", "jason")

data_frame %>% 
  separate_rows(names) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_split(tolower(names), paste0("(?<=(", paste0(patterns, collapse = "|"), "))"))) %>% 
  unnest(name) %>% 
  filter(nzchar(name)) %>% 
  group_by(j = cumsum(!(name == "j"))) %>% 
  summarise(name = paste(name, collapse = ""),
            id = unique(id)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(name = toString(name))

## A tibble: 5 × 2
#     id name                                                     
#  <dbl> <chr>                                                    
#1     1 john, jack, james                                        
#2     2 john, james, jason, james                                
#3     3 peter, jack, jason                                       
#4     4 jamesj, asonj, jack                                      
#5     5 jamesj, jason, john, jason, john, jason, jack, sam, peter
```

---

***Previous answer:***

Adding the other possible names in the patterns vector, and reordering the vector so that `jamesj` is preferred over `james`, you can then use `str_extract_all`.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

patterns <- c("john", "jack", "jamesj", "james", "jason", "asonj", "peter", "sam")
patterns <- patterns[order(nchar(patterns), decreasing = T)]

data_frame %>% 
  mutate(names = lapply(str_extract_all(tolower(names), paste(patterns, collapse = "|")), toString))

#  id                                                     names
#1  1                                         john, jack, james
#2  2                                 john, james, jason, james
#3  3                                        peter, jack, jason
#4  4                                       jamesj, asonj, jack
#5  5 jamesj, jason, john, jason, john, jason, jack, sam, peter
```

data

```r
data_frame <- tribble(
  ~id, ~names,
  1, "johnjack jameS",
  2, "john/james, jasonjames",
  3, "peter_jackjason",
  4, "jamesjasonj jack",
  5, "jamesjjason, johnjasonjohn , jason-jack sam _ peter"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this on my real frame and it doesnt seem to be working. I wonder if there might be some other way to write this code that might work? But thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: What’s not working? Can you detail a bit more why this answer is not enough?

Comment: I edited the asnwer to perfectly match your desired dataframe.

Comment: I believe if you sort your patterns from longer to shorter you won't have to adjust manually for the jamesj / james issue

Comment: that's a good point.

Comment: @antonoyaro8 see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Updated to retain whole names not in the pattern:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_frame <- tribble(
  ~id, ~names,
  1, "johnjack jameS",
  2, "john/james, jasonjames",
  3, "peter_jackjason",
  4, "jamesjasonj jack",
  5, "jamesjjason, johnjasonjohn , jason-jack sam _ peter"
)

patterns <- c("john", "jack", "jamesj", "james", "jason")

data_frame |> 
  mutate(names = map_chr(names, ~ str_to_lower(.) |> 
                           str_extract_all(str_c(c(patterns, "[a-z]{3,10}"), collapse = "|")) |> 
                           unlist() |> 
                           stringi::stri_remove_empty() |> 
                           str_c(collapse = ", "))
         )
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>      id names                                                    
#>   <dbl> <chr>                                                    
#> 1     1 john, jack, james                                        
#> 2     2 john, james, jason, james                                
#> 3     3 peter, jack, jason                                       
#> 4     4 jamesj, asonj, jack                                      
#> 5     5 jamesj, jason, john, jason, john, jason, jack, sam, peter
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The whole point of my question - suppose the name "peter" IS NOT in the "patterns" data frame.  Will this code you have provided still be able to somewhat run when names in "data_frame" are there that are not NOT present in "patterns"? Thanks!

Comment: Updated to keep names not in the pattern

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what rules you are supposed to follow to generate the final output since there seems to be a lot going on.

Here's is what I assumed which are the rules I coded into the `regular expressions` and the patterns they are replaced with (*..let me know if I'm wrong*)

1. Add a `,`  after matched words if they occur immediately before any alphabet using regex `"jack(?=[:alpha:])"`   *(This is for the words in the middle of the text, followed by other words)*
2. Replace special characters other than a `,` with a `,`  using regex `'(?!,)[:punct:]'` (*a special negative lookahead like regular expression pulled off from [source](https://localcoder.org/r-regex-remove-all-punctuation-except-apostrophe)*)
3. Add a `,` before spaces in between words, so   that are sandwiched between alphabets using regex `'(?<=[:alpha:]) (?=[:alpha:])'`
4. Account for the `jamesj` by ignoring the `james` followed by a `j` using regex `'james(?!j)(?=[:alpha:])'`

These regex are paired with their replacement texts in a named vector and passed into `str_replace_all` to do the substitutions.

I like the named vector approach to text substitution because you can print the vector and see at a glance what is going to be replaced with what.

Here's the full code as a reproducible example-

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Load the data frame
# Thanks to @Mael for the code
.df <- tribble( 
  ~id, ~names,
  1, "johnjack jameS",
  2, "john/james, jasonjames",
  3, "peter_jackjason",
  4, "jamesjasonj jack",
  5, "jamesjjason, johnjasonjohn , jason-jack sam _ peter"
)

# Load the pattern to place commas after; 
# Note jamesj comes before james, which is a sub-pattern of (james)j 
patterns <- c("john", "jack", "jamesj", "james", "jason")
```

```r
# Create a named vector for the string substitutions, format :  c('regex pattern' = 'replacement', ..)
sub_pattern <- setNames(object = paste0(patterns, ', '), # append comma and space
                        nm = paste0(patterns, '(?=[:alpha:])')) # for words occurring immediately before any alphabet

# Address james and jamesj double matching
names(sub_pattern) <- 
  str_replace(names(sub_pattern),
              'james(?!j).*', # replace the james matcher with
              'james(?!j)(?=[:alpha:])') # ensures james is not followed by a j 

# additional substitutions                        
sub_pattern <- append(sub_pattern,
                      c('(?!,)[:punct:]' = ', ', # replace non comma punctuations with a comma and space
                        '(?<=[:alpha:]) (?=[:alpha:])' = ', ')) # insert comma for spaces between words
                        # '[:space:],' = ',' # remove spaces before comma if needed

# Perform the string substitutions to the names column
newdf <- mutate(.df, names_with_comma = str_replace_all(tolower(names), sub_pattern))
# converting all the text to lower case (for the S in first column, if that's not a typo..)

newdf$names_with_comma
#> [1] "john, jack, james"                                           
#> [2] "john, james, jason, james"                                   
#> [3] "peter, jack, jason"                                          
#> [4] "jamesj, asonj, jack"                                         
#> [5] "jamesj, jason, john, jason, john , jason, jack, sam ,  peter"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And full credits to my eternal regular expression support from the [StringR cheatsheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/strings.pdf) and thanks to @Maël for the code for the data frame

Answer (score 1):

`paste` `|` between the `patterns` and compare it with the `tolower` `data_frame$names` and on match add   on both sides of the match using `gsub`.
Replace `/_, -` with `,`  using `gsub`.
`trimws` where whitespace is `,`

```
data_frame$names <-
  trimws( gsub("[/_, -]+", ", ",
               gsub( paste0("(", paste(patterns, collapse="|"), ")"), " \\1 ",
                    tolower(data_frame$names) )
               )
       , whitespace = ", ")
data_frame
#  id                                                     names
#1  1                                         john, jack, james
#2  2                                 john, james, jason, james
#3  3                                        peter, jack, jason
#4  4                                       jamesj, asonj, jack
#5  5 jamesj, jason, john, jason, john, jason, jack, sam, peter
```

Data:

```
patterns <- c("john", "jack", "james", "jamesj", "jason")

data_frame <- data.frame(id=1:5, names = c("johnjack jameS",
  "john/james, jasonjames", "peter_jackjason", "jamesjasonj jack",
  "jamesjjason, johnjasonjohn , jason-jack sam _ peter"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crossing()` from `tidyr` in combination with `str_detect()` from `stringr` to find each of the patterns by id.

```
names_from_pattern <- data_frame|> tidyr::crossing(patterns)  %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::filter(stringr::str_detect(names, patterns))|>
  dplyr::select(id, "names" = patterns)
```

Then find all other names **not** in the pattern

```
find.string <- paste(patterns, collapse = "|") #e.g. 'or' separated 
other_names <- tibble(id = data_frame$id, other_names = gsub(find.string, replacement = " ", x = data_frame$names)) %>%
tidytext::unnest_tokens(., input = other_names, output = names)
# removes remaining non-letters (e.g "peter", not "peter_")
other_names$names<- gsub("[^a-z]","",other_names$names)
```

RBind names from the pattern with other all names

```
df<- rbind(names_from_pattern, other_names)
```

Then to format the output to your specification, use dplyr's `pivot_wider()` in combination with `unite()` from `tidyr`.

```
df <-   df |>  
pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = names, values_from = names) %>%
unite(.,col='names', 2:length(.), sep=', ', na.rm = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id names                                       
  <int> <chr>                                       
1     1 jack, james, john                           
2     2 james, john, jason                          
3     3 jack, jason, peter                          
4     4 jack, james, jason, jamesj, asonj           
5     5 jack, james, john, jason, jamesj, peter, sam
```

libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)
```